# Laravel Request validation rename field

Tags: php, laravel

I use pickadate.js and have a problem with the laravel validation. If I send the form with the datepicker to my application, then there are two fields. `birthday` and `birthday_submit`. The last is created by pickadate.js and contains the date in the following format: `yyyy/mm/dd`.

My model has the column `birthday`. And my validation looks the following:

```php
$request->validate([
            "first_name"=>"required_without:last_name",
            "email"=>"nullable|email",
            "birthday_submit"=>"nullable|date"
        ]);
```

If I pass it to the `create()` function (Eloquent) then I get the error, that `birthday_submit` doesn't exist.

Is there a way to rename `birthday_submit` to `birthday` so I can mass assign it? Also the error messages would be better because the user shouldn't get the error message that `birthday_submit` is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can 'interfere' with the `$request` parameter by doing something like this before validation:

```
$request->merge(['birthday' => $request->birthday_submit]);
```

Basically you insert another field inside the `$request` with key `birthday` and the value of `birthday_submit`

Then you can use this field in the validation.